# How does Cursor observability work in Android?

Tags: android

I want to make a ContentProvider that acts like a proxy toward information on a remote server.  It is possible that the server can spontaneously update its information and send that update to my ContentProvider.  My goal is then to have a ListView that displays the data retrieved from the ContentProvider and updates automatically if the underlying data changes.

My question: if a client is using a ContentResolver to access my ContentProvider, and they get a Cursor using a the query() method, how will they be notified if new data arrives?  That is, will the Cursor object itself somehow be notified?  How does this Cursor observability work?

FYI, I am thinking of using a MatrixCursor within the ContentProvider, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your ContentProvider should call ContentResolver.notifyChange() for the changed URI. You should use the Loader API provided in the v4 compatibility jar (and it ships with honeycomb and later), have your Activity or Fragment implement the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface, and that will handle updating your UI when notifyChange is called.

Docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html

Tutorial:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem. Register a content observer on the cursor using registerContentObserver(). It's not necessary to use a ContentProvider if yours is the only app that's looking at the data.

Also, it's probably easier to poll the server rather than push updates. After all, even if the data changes, the device user doesn't care until he/she is looking at the data. If your activity comes to the foreground, you could either automatically sync to the server or ask the user if he/she wants to sync. Remember that you're not guaranteed to have a connection to the network, so it's better to pull when the network's available than it is to push. And easier, since the server doesn't have to figure out if your device is available.

Search code.google.com for C2DM for push. For pull, consider using sync adapters. There's an example in SampleSyncAdapter.